# Infix to Prefix algorithm

Tags: c++, prefix, infix-notation

I need to transform a `Infix` expression into a `Prefix` expression. My algorithm works for expression without parenthesis, but when I add parenthesis this algorithm doesn't work anymore.

The problem is that when there is two operators in the stack, the algorithm tries to get the left and the right operand, but it can happen that there is just one operand in the stack. For example `(1+2)`: the algorithm pushes `(` and `+` in the `operator` stack and `1` in the `operand` stack, but I need the other operand (the `2`). I think My code is broken in my while when I try to access to top of the `operand` stack (that is empty)

Here is my code :

```
void transformerenprefixe(vector<string> tableau)
{
    stack<string> Operand;
    stack<string> Operator;

    string token;
    string operatorElm;
    string rightOperand;
    string leftOperand;


    for (size_t i = 0; i < tableau.size(); i++)
    {
        token = tableau.at(i);
        if (checkOperand(token))
        {
            Operand.push(token);
        }
        else if (token == "(" || Operator.empty() || precedence(token) > precedence(Operator.top()))
        {
            Operator.push(token);
        }
        else if(token == ")")
        {
            while (Operator.top() != "(")
            {
                operatorElm = Operator.top();
                Operator.pop();
                rightOperand = Operand.top();
                Operand.pop();
                leftOperand = Operand.top();
                Operand.pop();
                string operande = operatorElm + leftOperand + rightOperand;
                Operand.push(operande);
            }
            operatorElm = Operator.top();
            Operator.pop();
        }
        else if(precedence(token) <= precedence(Operator.top()))
        {
            while (!Operator.empty() && precedence(token) <= precedence(Operator.top()))
            {
                operatorElm = Operator.top();
                Operator.pop();
                rightOperand = Operand.top();
                Operand.pop();
                leftOperand = Operand.top();
                Operand.pop();
                string operande = operatorElm + leftOperand + rightOperand;
                Operand.push(operande);
            }
            Operator.push(token);
        }
    }

    while (!Operator.empty())
    {
        operatorElm = Operator.top();
        Operator.pop();
        rightOperand = Operand.top();
        Operand.pop();
        leftOperand = Operand.top();
        Operand.pop();
        string operande = operatorElm + leftOperand + rightOperand;
        Operand.push(operande);
    }

    cout << "The prefix expression is : " << Operand.top() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Where / What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Yes there is a problem with my parentheses-handling...but i don't know how to solve it

Comment: "I think I see the problem" Ok, well, what is it that you see? Just because X doesn't work doesn't mean you know where the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that when there is two operators in the stack the algorithm try to get the left and the right operand, but it can happen that there is just one operand in the stack, for example (1+2) : the algorithm push ( and + in the operator stack and 1 in the operand stack, but I need another operand (the 2)

Comment: Add this to your question, it helps to understand what is going on with this code, and where the problem specifically lies.

Comment: Done, I hope it's understandable

Comment: Have you looked at this through a debugger?

Comment: Further editing is recommended. There is still danger of this question being closed for lacking an [mcve]. Why an MCVE? Well, it could be we're lazy, but the reason I like them is the act of whittling the program down to the point where it is the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug  almost always leads to the asker seeing the bug and how to fix it. This is far more educational for the asker than just about all of Stack Overflow's answers.

Comment: This looks mostly like a minimal example, but it is not complete/verifiable as we have no test cases for which it is failing.

Comment: You might want to look more in to prefix notation  You can have multiple operands take as an argument the result of an operation in prefix notation like (* A + B C D) => (A * (B+C+D)) see: [http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html)